# Why my program is not printing string?

Tags: c++

My program takes name and age of student and this function should find print the name of youngest,eldest student , and average age.However it does not prints name of youngest student can anyone tell me why?

```
void check(string *nameStudent, int *ageStudent, int num) {
    int i, young = 0, old = 0, sum = 0, mov = 0;
    string a, b;
    double average;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++){
        if (*(ageStudent + mov) < young) {
            young = *(ageStudent + mov);
            a = *(nameStudent + mov);
        }
        if (*(ageStudent + mov) > old) {
            old = *(ageStudent + mov);
            b = *(nameStudent + mov);
        }
        sum += *(ageStudent + mov);
        mov++;
    }
    average = (double) sum / num;
    cout << a << " Is youngest student and " << b << " Is oldest student " << endl << average << " is average age of students";
}
```

Comment: Because all students are older than `0`.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Including *how* you call this function and with what arguments.

Comment: FYI, `*(ageStudent+mov)` can be written more clearly as `ageStudent[mov]`

Comment: @alcedine : you should turn that into an answer

Comment: i am not allowed to use `ageStudent[mov]` in this program

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn to use your debugger.

Comment: use debbuger and you will know

Comment: This is not proper C++... It is using C++ types in a C-like way. Don't do that.

Comment: @K163759HarisBaig Then i'd start learning from somewhere else, you should be able to interpret `*(ageStudent+mov)` but as already stated `ageStudent[mov]` is clearer but also far more generic, almost all list classes have overloaded the `[]` operator. You should never actually write `*(ageStudent+mov)`

Comment: i am a beginner! Can you treat me as it i cannot understand !

Comment: Anyone got any idea why we are seeing this sudden rash of questions all using `*(ptr + index)` rather than the much more obvious `ptr[index]`?

Comment: @MartinBonner Maybe it's the time in the semester when they try to teach about pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @Barmar yes! How do you know? Are you a teacher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize `young` to `0`. It will only change `young` and `a` if there's a student whose age is less than `0`.

Instead of hard-coding the initial values of all these variables, get them from the first elements of the arrays.

```
if (num > 0) {
    young = old = sum = *ageStudent;
    a = b = *nameStudent;
}
```

Then you can change your loop to start from `1` instead of `0`, since you've already processed the first element of the array.

BTW, there's no need for the `mov` variable, since it always contains the same thing as `i`. Use `*(ageStudent + i)` instead.

```
void check(string *nameStudent, int *ageStudent, int num) {
    int i, young = 0, old = 0, sum = 0;
    string a, b;
    double average;
    if (num > 0) {
        young = old = sum = *ageStudent;
        a = b = *nameStudent;
    }
    for (i = 1; i < num; i++){
        if (*(ageStudent + i) < young) {
            young = *(ageStudent + i);
            a = *(nameStudent + i);
        }
        if (*(ageStudent + i) > old) {
            old = *(ageStudent + i);
            b = *(nameStudent + i);
        }
        sum += *(ageStudent + i);
        mov++;
    }
    average = num ? (double) sum / num : 0; // prevent division by 0
    cout << a << " Is youngest student and " << b << " Is oldest student " << endl << average << " is average age of students";
}
```

Comment: Personally I would start the function with `if (num <= 0) { cout << "No students\n"; return } and then stop worrying about a non-zero number of students.  One could usefully delay declaring `average` until needed, and it should be const.  nameStudent, ageStudent should be const pointer to const.  Finally, I wouldn't capitalize the "is" in the literals (it's not the first word of the sentence).

Comment: I was thinking of that, but wanted to keep my changes to a minimum. Plus, I got to show how to guard against division by 0.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful but what is function of _italic_ **bold** `average= num ? (double) sum/ num :0` what is _italic_ **bold** `?` and _italic_ **bold** `: 0` doing? also what are the names of these operator
by the way yes i could have used _italic_ **bold** `*(ageStudent + i)` but that was not allowed

Comment: @HarisBaig See [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Comment: Why do you spell out the words "italic" and "bold" in your comment?

Comment: "I could have used `*(ageStudent + i)` but that was not allowed." - I strongly suspect you have misunderstood the prohibition.  I can just about believe you have been told you may not use array indexing yet, and must do everything in terms of explicit pointer arithmetic.  I don't believe they required you to invent a second variable `mov`.

Comment: Oooh!  I wonder if they wanted you to increment `ageStudent` and `nameStudent` as you went through the list (and the prohibition was against writing `*(ageStudent + anything)`, rather than specifically `*(ageStudent + i)`

Comment: I am new in this website ! @Barmar

Comment: @Martin Bonner the question says i can not use loop variable inside loop! Is there any other way to do this without using other variable ? I hope you believe me now!

Comment: you mean `*(ageStudent + +)`?

Comment: Yes, that's what they mean: `*(ageStudent++)

Answer (score 1):

You're keeping the age of the youngest student in `young`, but initializing it to `0`, so of course none of the students in the list are going to satisfy `ageStudent[i] < young`. Initialize it to a large value instead. Generally, the largest value that the type in question (`int`) can take is preferred. If that sounds complicated to you, you can use something like `1000` in this case, as long as none of your students are going to be over a thousand years old.

Answer (score 0):

Set initial young to the maximum integer to force the comparison that is setting **a**.

Strictly speaking the initial **old** should be negative maximum (signed) integer to handle all formally possible cases and also the **num**=0 case should be adressed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the variable `young`.
You initialize it here to `0`:

```
int i, young = 0, old = 0, sum = 0, mov = 0;
```

Then you check it here:

```
if (*(ageStudent + mov) < young) {
```

But the `ageStudent` variable will always be greater than 0, as long as nobody of your students is under 0 years old, so the condition will always evaluate to `false`.

You can solve the problem by setting young to a high number at the beginning of your function.